# Как поменять поле Id из string в int ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc

всем пользователям. В .net mvc совсем новичок, пишу дипломную работу с данной технологией. У меня есть стандартная от майкрософт регистрация/авторизация пользователя на сайте, по задумке пользователь - это врач, он может регистрировать пациента. Регистрацию пациента написал сам, для нее есть отдельная таблица. Хочу теперь, чтобы когда врач регистрировал пациента, пациент закреплялся за ним, в интернете почитал что используется для этого вторичный ключ в БД. Нашел пример того, как это делается: ***CONSTRAINT [FK_Pacients_AspNetUsers] FOREIGN KEY ([IdUser]) REFERENCES [AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE SET NULL***
Где: Pacients - таблица пациентов, который были созданы врачом, AspNetUsers - соотв. сама таблица с врачами и их данными, IdUser - Id пациента, Id - Id врача, только суть в том, что 2 Id должны быть одного типа, в моем случае в таблице AspNetUsers - Id - тип string, как можно поменять из string в Id? В модели заходил, Idшник врача скрыт от программиста, так что просто поменять не получается, помогите кто может. Или же предложит другой вариант как закреплять пациента за врачом

Comment: Без кода и схемы данных тут не о чем говорить. Куда и зачем вы заходили и что там не получилось непонятно. Вообще ваша задача не ясна.

Comment: `в моем случае в таблице AspNetUsers - Id - тип string, как можно поменять из string в Id` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity это как минимум. Что после этого нужно сделать - решительно непонятно, потому что вы не привели код ваших моделей. На будущее: не стоит описывать код словами, просто приведите его - будет намного понятнее.